# Why my 16x16 LED matrix show only lines?

Tags: arduino, sensor, led, matrix

I bought from the web **one of this matrices**: [Link](https://www.emartee.com/Modules/bbs/redirect.php?tid=711&goto=lastpost)

I followed all instructions and I connected it to my Arduino Uno **without sensor shield** (it's necessary?).

I've used **IN pins** of the matrix in this way:

> Arduino digital pin 4,5,6,7 to input pin OIA,OIB,OIC,OID of LED screen
> Arduino digital pin 8,9,10 to pin SER,SCK,RCK of LED screen LED screen
> GND to Arduino ground and VCC of LED screen to Arduino power

I've also uploaded code.

But, using the code (as show in the link) my matrix **shows me only lines without characters**!!

I also changed `#define ScreenNO 4` to `#define ScreenNO 1` because i've only one 16x16 matrix.

Screenshots:
[image]
[image]

What could be the cause?
What's wrong in wires or code?

thanks all!

Comment: Could you please post a proper schematic?

Comment: @Leon The schema is in the posted link. I followed the instructon as shown. Schema is here: http://www.emartee.com/Attachment.php?name=41903.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the display is square, it's not clear which way is "up".  One would expect the top row to be nearest the top of the picture, but sometimes things can be surprising.

My guess would be that rows are indeed horizontal, and the LSB of the OIA/B/C/D wires is not connected properly or is otherwise not working and the display is always seeing it as "high".  This causes only the odd-numbered rows to be illuminated.

Without knowing exactly what you're trying to display, it's hard to determine what problems there might be beyond that; seeing what patterns are displayed when the row-select pin is fixed may reveal other issues.

Comment: The photo is in UP way as you see and i trying to display ":) arduino". For the wires, i followed exactly documentation as showed in link, i hope there are corrected... but i don't understand why it don't work!

Comment: It does not appear that the LSB of the row select is working.  Without a schematic of the LCD board I can't tell for sure whether it's the OIA or OID wire that's not working, nor whether it's stuck high or low, but one of the OIx wires doesn't seem to be behaving as it should.  Try disconnecting them individually and see what happens.  My guess is that disconnecting OIA will have no effect.